# How to secure a single page in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have no authentication required for my application, but want to secure a few pages.

On the page I wish to secure I have specified that user should not be a public user.

When I click a link to the page I do get a login box, but I seem to be able to enter any old rubbish and still proceed to the page.

How do I secure an individual page without a general authentication scheme at application level, so an Apex user account is needed.

Comment: What does "without a general authentication scheme" mean to you?  Without writing a custom authentication scheme, you can simply use the pre-packaged authentication scheme that ensures that a user is a valid APEX user and to create an authorization scheme based on that.  But you would need some way of authenticating a user.

Comment: Ah...wait a minute. I had Apex authentication set, but no authentication function defined...changed it to BUILTIN and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to do it the other way around: apply an authentication scheme to your application, then mark individual pages as Public (i.e. not requiring authentication) except for the page that requires authentication.